# In editor.tokenColorCustomizations, how can I apply a rule only to files with a given extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code

I'm using Visual Studio Code with the Gruvbox theme. I have the following configuration in my `settings.json`:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Gruvbox Dark Medium]": {
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                    "scope": "source.c, entity.name.function.preprocessor",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#eb9b82"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

This colors C macros differently than the default. This works as expected, except that if I open a Rust file, Rust macros are also colored differently, despite the `source.c` in the `scope` field. How can I have this settings apply only to C files? Rust macros have the exclamation mark at the end which differentiate them from regular function, I don't a different color for them.

EDIT:
Here is what the VSCode token inspector shows *without* the above settings for the `println!` macro:

[image: 1]

Here is what the VSCode token inspector shows *with* the above settings enabled:

[image: 2]

Comment: you can add this setting to a languageID specific group

Comment: @rioV8 ??? `editor.tokenColorCustomizations` is not registered for language override if that's what you mean...

Comment: please show what you see in the token scope inspector. And what Rust extensions for VS Code are you using? give their extension IDs please.

Comment: @starball I'm using rust-analyzer (ID: rust-lang.rust-analyzer). I've edited the question with screenshots of the token inspector before and after the settings modification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mark noticed, you have a comma between your two things. You wanted a descendent selector, but you turned it into grouping. See https://macromates.com/manual/en/scope_selectors. Remove the comma.

You could just use [semantic highlighting](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/semantic-highlight-guide) customization instead?

```json
"editor.semanticTokenColorCustomizations": {
    "[Your Theme Name Here]": { // TODO put your theme name here, or remove this wrapper to apply regardless of current theme
        "rules": {
            "macro.defaultLibrary:rust": {
                "foreground": "#FF0000", // TODO
                // "fontStyle": "bold",
            },
        },
    },
},
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm no expert on VSCode config, I'm not even sure about the difference between `semanticTokenColorCustomizations` and `tokenColorCustomizations`. Anyway, I've changed your suggestion by using `macro:c` instead, to only color C macros.

Answer (score 0):

You were close with your original attempt.  Try this instead:

```json
"editor.tokenColorCustomizations": {
        "[Gruvbox Dark Medium]": {
            "textMateRules": [
                {
                    // remove the comma
                    "scope": "source.c entity.name.function.preprocessor",
                    "settings": {
                        "foreground": "#eb9b82"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    },
```

The comma between scopes makes them `alternatives` so the rule is being applied to `source.c` and to `entity.name.function.preprocessor` separately.

But you want to modify (i.e., limit) the scopes - in that case you do not use a comma to separate the scopes but just a space.

[I can't actually duplicate your language/macro environment so I can't test this as I usually do.]

Comment: Removing the comma doesn't solve the issue. Both C and Rust's macros are not colored with the color I specify. It seems VSCode is not able the parse `"scope": "source.c entity.name.function.preprocessor"`.

Comment: Note that I've also tried using `source.cpp`.

Comment: Also try reversing them, put the `source.c` last.  What extension are you using for the `macro.defaultLibrary`?  Also it is possible that there is a more specific scope, like `entity.name.function.macro.rust` which is a better match.